# Getting ExceptionInInitializerError while trying to mock Static references of a class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

Trying to Mock abstract class where there is returning one static method ref. Getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.prac.get.Helper.registerF(Helper.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:109)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143) 
    at com.customization.project.RicherTest.testOrder(RicherTest.java:292) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53) 
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) 
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.util.Ref.registerConverter(Ref.java:383) 
    at com.config.ControlConfig.<clinit>(ControlConfig.java:55) 
    ... 46 more
```

---

Used Suppressed warnings and PrepareForTest fuly qualified names to suppress this after checking with many online help

```java
@Test
public void testOrder() { 
    IManager projectOrderManager = Mockito.mock(IManager.class);    
    ProjectFactory factory = Mockito.mock(ProjectFactory.class); 

    //ProjectFactory is abstract class
    mFactory(ProjectFactory.class, factory);    

    PowerMockito.when(factory.createInterface()).thenReturn(projectOrderManager);
    PowerMockito.when(projectOrderManager.getID(sessioncontext.getOrder().getProjectID(), sessionMocked)).thenReturn(projectOrder);
```

```java
protected final void mFactory(Class factoryClass, Object factory2return) {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(factoryClass, new Class[0]);

    try {
        PowerMockito.when(factoryClass, "getInstance", new Object[0]).thenReturn(factory2return);
    } catch (Exception var) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to have factory <%s>.", factoryClass.getName()), var);
    }
}
```

Actual error when trying to run:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Try to update your question and make it a bit more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Let me know if this is not good, trying to set up with code standards.

Comment: It got resolved by suppressing static blocks till all the path of the class were written.

DO wonder why this is necessary in this.

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer, try adding the relevant parts to your question. The `NPE` seems to be raised by a static block in `ControlConfig`. You might want to add that part to your question. Also please post a complete testcase and describe (and add the code) the relation between your test classes and `ControlConfig`.

Comment: Thanks, although now, I fixed it, it is second to the part of NPE. Main issue was ExceptioninInitializer error
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/06/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-exceptionininitializerError-fix.html --> this blog really helped me to know aware on this issue.

Apart from that, suppressing static checks really did the trick for me, however, i do wonder, why end to end package naming was necessary to overcome this tricky error.